# Telgram for business ( like whatsapp for business)

Tags: integration, whatsapp

I would like to explore sending messages through Telegram for my app. We have integrated whatasapp already but with the popularity in Telegram.  I know that Telegram provides developer API but have not seen it being used in any app.

Any references and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project to integrates Telegram o a CLI, maybe could be useful to automate a bot

https://github.com/vysheng/tg

You should check telegram API Doc to see the default way to integrate it
https://core.telegram.org/api